# Tag synonym request [scroll] → [scrolling]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

I just submitted a tag wiki for [scroll](/questions/tagged/scroll) but noticed that there is a [scrolling](/questions/tagged/scrolling) with an already established wiki that is a pretty good synonym for scroll.  I don't have points in scroll yet but would like to suggest it as a synonym of scrolling.

Comment: [So proposed.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scroll/synonyms) Come one, come all, cast your votes!

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Synonym proposition system sucks, do you know? "You do not have the required score on this tag to vote for this tag synonym". It's a crap so much.

Comment: I was about to post the exact same request just now, September 24th. That's *eight months* in which nothing happened. Come on guys, can't be that hard!